# How to calcualte the Big-O complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

I have been trying to calculate the Big-O of the following algorithm and it is coming out to be O(n^5) for me. I don't know what the correct answer is but most of my colleagues are getting O(n^3).

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1 ; j <= i*i ; j++)
    {
        for(k=1 ; k<= n/2 ; k++) 
        {
        x = y + z;
        }
     }
}
```

What I did was start from the innermost loop. So I calculated that the innermost loop will run `n/2` times, then I went to the second nested for loop which will run `i^2` times and from the outermost loop will run `i` times as `i` varies from `1` to `n`. This would mean that the second nested for loop will run a total of `Sigma(i^2) from i=1 to i=n` so a total of `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6` times. So the total amount that the code would run came out to be in the order of `n^5` so I concluded that the order must be `O(n^5)`. Is there something wrong with this approach and the answer that I calculated?

I have just started with DSA and this was my first assignment so apologies for any basic mistakes that I might have made.

Comment: The third (inner) loop runs `n/2` times, each time the second loop runs. The second loop runs `(2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)/6` times. How do you get from there to "the order of `n^5`"?

Comment: I multiplied the times all the loops run. 1st loop runs `n` times, 2nd one runs `(2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)/6` times and the 3rd one runs `n/2` times. So the maximum degree of n comes out to be 5 on multiplication.

Comment: This is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No, the second one runs `i^2` times each time the first runs, `(2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)/6` times *in total;* don't multiply it by `n` again.

Comment: Oh I see, so when should I really multiply or add when calculating the complexity? Also, the order according to you should be `n^3` then?

Comment: I think n^4 complexity

Comment: The order of the second loop is `n^3`. The third loop runs `n/2` times *each time the second loop runs,* so the order of the whole thing is `n^4`. As for stating an exact general rule for when to multiply or add... I'd have to think about that one.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop always has the same number of iterations (*n*/2), since it is independent of *i* and *j*. On its own it has a complexity of *O(n)*.

The two other loops result in a sum of sequence of squares (1 + 4 + 9 + ...) of executions of the inner part.

This sum of squares corresponds to the [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), and has an order of *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*.

The inner loop has an order of *O(n)*, so we get *O(n<sup>4</sup>)*.